# D3 Canvas Globe With Text At LongLat

Tags: javascript, d3.js, canvas

my question today is about D3 and display text on a globe at a long/lat using Canvas. What I've essentially got is a globe built using mbostock's world tour, which has a list of long/lats and rotates the globe to focus on them. I've already got markers at the points, but what I'd like is to display some text next to all of the points. At this point in time, it's just city names, but the intention is to display more information as the globe is more fully fleshed out. I've created a plunk with the code: https://plnkr.co/edit/CzfoF4bkPv93l3Yxwu3N?p=preview

The relevant code in that plunk is:

```
return function(t) {
    projection.rotate(r(t));
    c.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    c.fillStyle = "#ccc", c.beginPath(), path(land), c.fill();
    for (var j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {
        c.fillStyle = "#000", c.beginPath(), path(points[j]), c.fill();
    }
    c.strokeStyle = "#000", c.lineWidth = 2, c.beginPath(), path(globe), c.stroke();
};
```

Basically what I'm asking for is a way to display text slightly to the right of specific long/lat coordinates on a globe using canvas. Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to add a the text in your tween function after you draw the features:

```
c.fillText(points[i].location,projection(points[i].coordinates)[0]+10,projection(points[i].coordinates)[1]+2);
```

With the variable `projection`, `projection([long,lat])` returns `[x,y]`, in other words it gives the forward projection of a given point represented by latitude and longitude, returning a coordinate in map coordinate space (your svg or canvas).

Once you have the projected coordinates, you can manipulate those as needed. In this case I added ten to the x value to push the place name further to the right.  See [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZX24Ym5dcH8rqnhMtzr9?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for!